# No apk folder in Build Folder

Tags: android

My Application is running fine. I want to show the apk file but there is no folder of apk in the output folder. There is no error in project. What is main issue

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: You can see your apk in this folder : Project Path\app\build\outputs\apk

Comment: Have you checked the directory using Explorer/Nautilus of your OS? AndroidStudio may not always detect changes in the file-system and display outdated information.

Comment: @Robert I was missing to build to locally, I was running my project directly on my device. when i press Build->Build apk(s) then folder created in my output folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the apk file to appear in your Android studio directory, you need to build the project first. After building, the apk file should appear in this directory: Your-app\app\build\outputs\

To build, simply press *CTRL + F9*.

Comment: I was running directly on my device, forget to build it locally, thank you so much@Taslim